# Embedded Google Forms not working from Gmail App on Phone

Tags: forms, mobile, gmail, google-forms

I am using Google Scripts to generate a Google form and embed it to an email. It works fine when I submit the form from my browser, but when I try to submit the form from the App in my phone I get the message:

> "JavaScript
>
> Forms are disabled in Gmail"

I have tried to send the form from Google Forms itself, assuming the modified HTML could be affecting it, with no luck. It still shows the same message.

Is this something that can be solved or just a limitation from the App?

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you embedding the form into an email or into an app.

Comment: Into an email. It works fine in my browsers (also in my phone's browsers) but it doesn't in the Gmail App.

Comment: While it's true that you can add html to an email to add colorful effects.  It's not possible to interact with that html like you can with a WebSite. Google Forms require a web/browser environment to function properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Cooper Do you know if there's any way around it? The forms need to be replied from the gmail app to assure ergonomy.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, it is not possible to send dynamic forms that can be filled in within the Gmail app itself. This is due to the strict restrictions of the platform, that allow for  stronger safety for the end-user.

Quite recently, AMP for GMail has been enabled in the Android app. Although it is a state-of-the-art feature (and thus not all phones may support it, plus users will need to have a quite recent version of the app) it allows you to send messages that the receivers can interact with. You can learn more about this brand new feature here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/ampemail

Comment: Thanks for that input.